# Why we add a value to initialize the stack pointer (R7) in assembly?

Tags: assembly

I'm currently new into assembly. I know that we first need to allocate the dimension of the stack (in the example below is 1000). However I struggle to understand why we should add a value (in this case #999) to initialize the stack pointer.  Here's the pseudo-assembly:

```
STACK: .RES 1000

MOV #STACK, SP
ADD #999, SP
```

Comment: The stack grows down, but this code looks rather weird.

Comment: Yeah, it is actually a simplification of the "real assembly" made by my professor in order to understand the basics.

Comment: @fuz  So basically the address of the new stack pointer allows the insertion of new data between the before-and-after initialization space?

Comment: To allocate space on the stack, the stack pointer is decremented (i.e. the stack grows down).  Thus, in order to use the buffer `STACK` for the stack, the stack pointer has to initially point to the end of `STACK` so decrementing the stack pointer makes it point to new parts of `STACK`.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much for the clarification! :)

Comment: Why not `MOV #STACK+999, SP`?

Comment: A quick remind note: in 64 bit the stack pointer is linear, it is not relevant to a segment.

Comment: @TonyK: yup, that's what you'd normally write, so the stack pointer is never temporarily invalid, in case an interrupt happens while SP is pointing to the very bottom of the reserved region.  This is either an intentional de-optimization by the professor because they think it's better to avoid showing assemble-time expressions to avoid confusing students about what asm can do, or they didn't realize how silly this is. (Many beginners don't understand that asm as a language isn't like C, it only expresses what the machine can do in one instruction. Assemble-time vs. runtime might be confusing.)

Comment: @Michael: This is not an x86 question.  The title says "R7" is the stack pointer, and that's not AT&T or Intel syntax.  I don't think it's ARM or AArch64 either, because I've never seen `op  src, dest` order for those.

Comment: This is almost PDP-11: the syntax matches (e.g. `add #4, sp`, and `.directive` leading dots like GAS and Unix assemblers), but PDP-11's SP is R6, and its R7 is the program counter.  https://people.cs.clemson.edu/~mark/subroutines/pdp11.html  What is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allocate space on the stack, the stack pointer is decremented (i.e. the stack grows down).  Thus, in order to use the buffer `STACK` for the stack, the stack pointer has to initially point to the end of `STACK` so decrementing the stack pointer makes it point to new parts of `STACK`.